# jQuery: Using Multiple Arrays to Match Class Attribute Which Determines ChildNodes HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a weekly schedule that I update manually using a static table.

```
<table>
  <tr class="live al tv">
    <td>October 2</td>
    <td>12:30 pm</td>
    <td class="competition"></td>
    <td>Team A v Team B</td>
    <td class="field">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="be tv">
    <td>October 2</td>
    <td>6 pm</td>
    <td class="competition"></td>
    <td>Team C v Team D</td>
    <td class="field">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ga tv">
    <td>October 3</td>
    <td>12:30 pm</td>
    <td class="competition"></td>
    <td>Team D v Team A</td>
    <td class="field">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="live de tv">
    <td>October 3</td>
    <td>6 pm</td>
    <td class="competition"></td>
    <td>Team C v Team B</td>
    <td class="field">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have 2 arrays. This first one is the list of classes:

```
var compClass = new Array();
compClass[0] = 'al',
compClass[1] = 'be',
compClass[2] = 'ga',
compClass[3] = 'de';
```

The second one is the list of competitions:

```
var competitions = new Array();
competitions[0] = 'alpha',
competitions[1] = 'beta',
competitions[2] = 'gamma',
competitions[3] = 'delta';
```

What I'm trying to do is match the `compClass` array, respectively, to the `competitions` array. I want it so that if the `<tr>` class matches one of the `compClass` values, the inner text of its child element, `<td class="competition"></td>`, will auto-populate using the corresponding `competitions` value. If that doesn't make any sense, here's the jQuery I'm trying to use:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var rowClass = $('table tr[class*=" "]'),
        compCell = $('td.competition'),
        fieldCell = $('td.field');

    function setCompetition() {
      for(var i=0;i<compClass.length;++i) {
        $('tr').attr('class',compClass[i]).each(function() {
          this.children[2].innerHTML = competition[i];
        });
      }
    }

  });
});
```

I tried using `$.map()` but I couldn't get it to work. I'm a novice with jQuery--let alone JS in general. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone offer some guidance? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $.map() is the way to go. Perhaps you should share this code?

Comment: @ColinE Here's the jsFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/hH5m3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an object:

```
var compClass = {
    'al' : 'alpha',
    'be' : 'beta',
    'ga' : 'gamma',
    'de' : 'delta'
}
var k = Object.keys(compClass);

$('tr[class]').each(function() {
    var prop = $.grep(this.className.split(' '), function(value) {
                    return k.indexOf(value) > -1;
               })[0];

    if (prop) this.children[2].innerHTML = compClass[prop];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3wGmR/1/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$.map($("tr"), function(tr, i) {

        $.each(compClass, function(index, someClass){
            if ($(tr).hasClass(someClass)) {
                classIndex = compClass.indexOf(someClass);
                compVal = competitions[classIndex];
                $(tr).find(".competition").each(function() {this.innerHTML = compVal});
            };
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U7qWB/1/