# jQuery: Set Element Attributes Using Object Values and Subvalues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

I update a weekly schedule using the following static table:

```
<table>
  <tr class="live gm fsp">
    <td>Oct. 7</td>
    <td>12:30 pm</td>
    <td class="prog">Show 1</td>
    <td>Team A v Team B</td>
    <td class="tv-logo"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gm dtv">
    <td>Oct. 7</td>
    <td>4 pm</td>
    <td class="prog">Show 2</td>
    <td>Team C v Team D</td>
    <td class="tv-logo"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="usa gm pnc">
    <td>Oct. 7</td>
    <td>6 pm</td>
    <td class="prog">Show 3</td>
    <td>Team E v Team F</td>
    <td class="tv-logo"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gm pnc">
    <td>Oct. 7</td>
    <td>8 pm</td>
    <td class="prog">Show 3</td>
    <td>Team E v Team F</td>
    <td class="tv-logo"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `class` attribute of the `<tr>` element will determine the inner HTML of its `<td class="tv-logo"></td>` child element. The inner HTML is supposed to be a linked `<img/>` of the student TV channel logo. The image `src` and `alt` (which I will also use for its `title`) attributes are contained in the following object:

```
var networkClass = {
  'fsp' : {
    'src' : '/images/page-items/fsp.png',
    'alt' : 'First Student Productions'
  },
  'dtv' : {
    'src' : '/images/page-items/dtv.png',
    'alt' : 'Digital Travel Vlog'
  },
  'pnc' : {
    'src' : 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-i9U1bdKwzZk/UR3WRV2vDsI/AAAAAAAAAjw/FqBP37bYf5Y/s100/BMW_logo_black_white.png',
    'alt' : 'Production New Cinema'
  },
  'usa pnc' : {
    'src' : 'http://www.qservice.ro/assets/images/brands/slider_16.png',
    'alt' : 'Production New Cinema'
  }
}
```

The class `usa` sets the corresponding `<tr>` to have a solid colored background which requires the white version of the corresponding TV channel logo.

Using the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19220051/1155068) (or http://jsfiddle.net/3wGmR/1/), I can only match the class if it has a single value but not 2 values. How do I set the inner `<img/>` HTML of `<td class="tv-logo"></td>` while also setting it's attributes using the object? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the meaning of the key `pnc usa`? does it mean those properties has to be assigned to rows with both the classes `pnc` and `usa` or either one of them

Comment: @ArunPJohny Those properties have to be assigned to rows with both the `pnc` and `usa` classes.

Comment: as in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3JCab/2/ ?

Comment: so which image should be assigned to row `usa gm pnc` since it has 3 classes there are no matches with 3 classes... but there are 2 matches with 1 or more classes like in `pnc` and `pnc usa`

Comment: @ArunPJohny This should help in regards to `<img/>` use: http://jsfiddle.net/3JCab/5/

Comment: can you clarify the question above... with regards to what should happen to `pnc usa`

Comment: Just updated the fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/3JCab/5/

Comment: so the one with maximum match should gets applied, is it so?

Comment: @ArunPJohny If the `<tr>` has the class `usa`, the `img` to be rendered will be the alternate white version. The `pnc` class will render the standard black version while the `usa pnc` classes together will render the white version.

Answer (score 0):

If the keys in `networkClass` were valid CSS selectors then you could use `.is` to determine if the element in question satisfies them, and in this way reach the result you are looking for.

The keys are not selectors, but if we can assume they are whitespace-separated lists of CSS class names it's easy to transform them into selectors:

```
var key = "pnc usa";
var selector = key.replace(/(^|\s+)(\S+)/g, ".$2"); // ".pnc.usa"
```

So you can write this:

```
$('tr[class]').each(function() {
    var $tr = $(this);
    $.each(networkClass, function(key, attributes) {
        var selector = key.replace(/(^|\s+)(\S+)/g, ".$2");
        if ($tr.is(selector)) {
            $tr.children(".tv-logo").append($("<img>", attributes));
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

However, you have to pay attention to the details here: since `.foo` is a strictly less-specific selector than `.foo.bar` and the selector that matches first will determine the result, you must take care so that more specific selectors always appear before less-specific ones on the `networkClass` object:

```
var networkClass = {
  // this
  'pnc usa' : {
    'src' : '/images/page-items/pnc-white.png',
    'alt' : 'Production New Cinema'
  }
  // must appear before this
  'pnc' : {
    'src' : '/images/page-items/pnc.png',
    'alt' : 'Production New Cinema'
  },
}
```

Comment: @DaveyJake: That fiddle is for Arun's answer... :-)

Comment: Sorry about that. Just updated the question using a black & white version of the same image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this., **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mVtCD/1/)**

```
$('tr[class]').each(function() {
var cls = this.className.split(' ');

var f = $.grep(cls, function(value, i) {
    return k.indexOf(value) > -1;
})[0];

if (f) {        
    this.children[4].innerHTML = '<img src="'+compClass[f].src+'" alt="'+compClass[f].alt+'"/>';
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var $trs = $('table tr[class]');
$.each(networkClass, function (key, attrs) {
    var clazz = '.' + key.split(/\s+/).join('.');
    $trs.filter(clazz).find('.tv-logo').append($('<img />', attrs))
})
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3JCab/)